# distributed associative domains in Chapel

Tags: chapel

Are there any working examples of distributed domain maps for associative and/or opaque domains in Chapel, or any hints on how one would distribute a non-rectangular structure such as a graph over multiple locales? I know about distributed sparse arrays, but I am looking at less structured data. The documentation mentions a prototype domain map for associative domains -- is it available anywhere to experiment with? Thank you.

Answer (score 4):

Yes, these distributed associative domains are new in 1.19 (which as of this writing will be released soon, but you can try them out using a master branch before then). The documentation for them here has an example:

https://chapel-lang.org/docs/master/modules/dists/HashedDist.html